# Create RecyclerView List From Edit Text Content

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview

[image]
I have **RecyclerView** in fragment and i want when user press button below **"Add New Row"** it will redirect to new fragment till here there is no problem i can achieve it but now i want the **details filled in form** will show as **new row in recyclerview**

As you can see in image above user can add row in RecyclerView dynamically and also there is cross top right of every row which delete row from list.

So,**What i want to do is**

**1)** How i can add row to the list with form inputs as soon as user press **Save Event** then show user newly added row with his entered details in form

In short i want to add row dynamically from list with user inputs in form and also delete it from list when user press cross button at top right of row item

Comment: update your list or whatever container the adapter is using and then call notifyDataSetChanged() or notifyItemChanged  notifyItemInserted etc. on the adapter

Comment: that thing i know but how to update list with form data

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: i have simple recycler View and its adapter and one fragment as u see in second screen with edit text and third is same as first but with updated list

Comment: @androidXP you need to change the actual data that backs the `RecyclerView` adapter. E.g., if you have a `List` of events, add a new element to the `List` and then call `notifyItemInserted()` or an equivalent method.

Comment: @Karakuri can you please explain with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself what i did to get data back into first fragment from second fragment
First i create `interface` to send result to fragment_1(Which has recyclerview) from fragment_2(Which has form)

**Here is my form code**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.ppl_details_form,container,false);
        PPL_Title_Spinner= (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.PPL_Spinner);
        Title= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ppl_title);
        Address= (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ppl_address);
        Year= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ppl_passing_year);
        Description= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ppl_description);
        btn1= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ppl_map_button);

        Save= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ppl_save);
        Save_PPL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                title=Title.getText().toString();
                address= Address.getText().toString();
                year=Year.getText().toString();
                description=Description.getText().toString();
                //PPL Wrapper
                PPL_list_wrapper list=new PPL_list_wrapper(title,year,address);

                Add_PPL=(PPL_transfer_data_to_list)getActivity();
                Add_PPL.addLocation(list);
                fragment_1 fragment1=new fragment_1();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout,fragment1);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try{
            Add_PPL= (PPL_transfer_data_to_list) context;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()+" Must Implement Interface");
        }
    }
```

And then i implement infterface into Parent Activity and then call fragment_1 method from activity like this

```
 @Override
    public void addEvent(PPL_list_wrapper PPL_DATA) {
        fragment_1 recycler=new fragment_1();
        recycler.PPL_eve(PPL_DATA);

    }
```

Then i get data into fragment_1 and have to make arraylist in fragment `static` cause without static list will lost its reference and data too and it will stop showing data into recyclerview

```
 public void PPL_eve(final PPL_list_wrapper ppl_list_wrapper){
        PPL_wrapper=ppl_list_wrapper;   
        event_details.add(ppl_list_wrapper);//Static ArrayList
        adapter=new ppl_Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(),event_details);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

I have to make sure that my list is static

```
static List<PPL_list_wrapper> event_details=new ArrayList<PPL_list_wrapper>();
```